# Convert LaTeX document to HTML

Tags: haskell, regex

For a web application, I have to transform a LaTeX document on the fly into an HTML string, that is delivered to connected clients via websockets. Thus I installed a filewatcher that waits for file updates and whenever the file is modified, I run `transformToHTML` to parse the LaTeX code with regular expressions and build an HTML document.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy

-- transforms a LaTeX document to an HTML document
transformToHTML :: Text -> Text
transformToHTML latex =
    let raw = gsub [reM|\\(intertext|begin|end|textbf|textit|section|subsection|subsubsection|documentclass|usepackage|item)(?:{(.*?)})?(?:\[(.*?)\])*|] envs latex
        resolvedBreaks = gsub [re|(\\\\)(?![^\[]*\\\])|] ("<br>" :: Text) raw
    in gsub [reM|(\\begin{figure}(.*?)\\end{figure}|\\begin{tabular}(.*?)\\end{tabular})|]
        ("<p>Content not available in your country.</p>" :: Text) resolvedBreaks
  where envs :: [Text] -> Text
        envs ("begin":"enumerate":_) = "<ol>"
        envs ("end":"enumerate":_) = "</ol>"
        envs ("begin":"itemize":_) = "<ul>"
        envs ("end":"itemize":_) = "</ul>"
        envs ("begin":"definition":name:_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Definition" (Just name)
        envs ("begin":"definition":_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Definition" Nothing
        envs ("end":"definition":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"lemma":name:_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Lemma" (Just name)
        envs ("begin":"lemma":_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Lemma" Nothing
        envs ("end":"lemma":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"satz":name:_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Theorem" (Just name)
        envs ("begin":"satz":_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Theroem" Nothing
        envs ("end":"satz":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"korrolar":name:_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Corrolary" (Just name)
        envs ("begin":"korrolar":_) = lemmaLike "lemma" "Corrolary" Nothing
        envs ("end":"korrolar":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"bem":name:_) = lemmaLike "bsp" "Annotation" (Just name)
        envs ("begin":"bem":_) = lemmaLike "bsp" "Annotation" Nothing
        envs ("end":"bem":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"bsp":name:_) = lemmaLike "bsp" "Example" (Just name)
        envs ("begin":"bsp":_) = lemmaLike "bsp" "Example" Nothing
        envs ("end":"bsp":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"proof":name:_) = "<div class='proof'><i>Proof</i> (" <> name <> ")."
        envs ("begin":"proof":_) = "<div class='proof'><i>Proof</i>."
        envs ("end":"proof":_) = "</div>"
        envs ("begin":"align*":_) = "\\[\\begin{aligned}"
        envs ("end":"align*":_) = "\\end{aligned}\\]"
        envs ("begin":"document":_) = ""
        envs ("end":"document":_) = ""
        envs ("begin":tag:_) = "\\begin{" <> tag <> "}"
        envs ("end":tag:_) = "\\end{" <> tag <> "}"
        envs ("textbf":content:_) = surround "b" content
        envs ("textit":content:_) = surround "i" content
        envs ("section":content:_) = surround "h2" content
        envs ("subsection":content:_) = surround "h2" content
        envs ("subsubsection":content:_) = surround "h4" content
        envs ("intertext":content:_) = "\\\\ \\text{" <> content <> "} \\\\"
        envs ("item":_) = "<li>"
        envs _ = ""

lemmaLike :: Text -> Text -> Maybe Text -> Text
lemmaLike cls name Nothing = "<div class='" <> cls <> "'><b>" <> name <> "</b>."
lemmaLike cls name (Just title) = "<div class='" <> cls <> "'><b>" <> name <> "</b> (" <> title <> ")."

surround :: Text -> Text -> Text
surround surr content = "<" <> surr <> ">" <> content <> "</" <> surr <> ">"
```

Is there a better way to efficiently parse a LaTeX document? One major issues here is, that I run through the document thrice and apply `gsub`.

Also I think this is not really readable and it is hard to figure out, what is going on.

Comment: May be a silly question, but can't you simply use `pandoc`?

Comment: Did you try [LaTeX2HTML](https://www.latex2html.org)? It seems to do the job you want.